# Compactness and connectedness of the topological space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Let $X=\mathbb N$ be equipped with the topology generated by the basis consisting of sets $A_n = \{n,n+1,n+2,\ldots\} ,n \in \mathbb N $ . Then $X$ is

1. compact and connected
2. Hausdorff and connected
3. Hausdorff and compact
4. Neither compact nor connected

My attempt is

Let $ A_n \text{ and }  A_m$ be two distinct basis elements . If $n > m$, then $A_n \cap A_m = A_n$. So intersection of two non empty open set is not empty. So $(X,\tau)$ is not Hausdorff but connected .

Please tell me about compactness.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean to say that $(X,\tau)$ is not disconnected, i.e. is connected?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom:sorry I am edding , it is connectd.

Comment: Regarding compactness: suppose $\mathcal U$ is an arbitrary open cover. Choose an $U\in\mathcal U$. This $U$ contains all but finitely many natural numbers, so it only remains to make sure these missing numbers are covered using finitely many elements of $\mathcal U$.

Answer (score 2):

First note that the topology generated by the basis you describe above consists of the following sets: $$\{ \varnothing \} \cup \{ A_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \},$$ *i.e.*, the only open set you have not explicitly mentioned is the empty set.  This follows from the fact that $A_m \cap A_n = A_{\max \{m,n\}}$, and for a nonempty $B \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, $\bigcup \{ A_n : n \in B \} = A_{\min B}$.  From here you should be able to easily conclude that $X$ is not T<sub>1</sub>, let alone Hausdorff.  (I guess this only makes sense if you have been introduced to the [T<sub>1</sub> property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space).)

For compactness I'll just leave the following

**Hint:** Which sets in this topology contain the *least* natural number (be that $0$ or $1$)?